# Neo4j Cypher query with timestamp

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to query the db for the 10 most recently created nodes. I have attempt

```
MATCH (a:Post) RETURN a ORDER BY TIMESTAMP() LIMIT 10
```

I have also tried this

```
MATCH (a:Post) RETURN a ORDER BY TIMESTAMP() DESC LIMIT 10
```

If I create nodes with contents {one, two, three} in that order, both queries produce the nodes in the order one, two, three. Any thoughts or ideas as to why this happens??

Comment: wouldn't a simple `ORDER BY n.timestamp DESC LIMIT 10` solve this?

Comment: I attempted to implement the DESC however it gives me the same results, do you have to specify a timestamp attribute for the nodes or is it created automatically?

Comment: You have to specify it yourself when the node is created: `CREATE (:Post {title:{title},content:{content},timestamp:timestamp()})`

Comment: That makes a bit more sense however I created another test scenario and when I pull them I can see the timestamp and the order however when I match and order by timestamp with and without desc they appear in the same order??

Answer (score 12):

`TIMESTAMP()` is a [scalar function](http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp) to mean the exact time at query execution. It does not have anything to do with the time the nodes or relationships were created.

That is why you get the exact same results for both queries. You're simply ordering by the current time, which doesn't make a lot of sense because the current time is exactly the same for all records.

Neo4j does not store any creation timestamps by default. You need to store them as an additional property, if it's important to you. This is where you should use the scalar function.

```
CREATE (:Post {created_at: TIMESTAMP()})
```

Once that is done, match and order like this.

```
MATCH (a:Post) RETURN a ORDER BY a.created_at LIMIT 10
```

Note that you're ordering by the `created_at` property, and not the `TIMESTAMP()` scalar function.